# Issue comparing Date with the same Format

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, testing, time

I have to make an if function with comparaison of two Date :
The First Date is Time.
The second Date is a date comes from a fixed date.

My Code :

```
if (Time == contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59))
{
True
}
else
{
False
}
```

I have test my format with a :

```
  Debug ("contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59) :" + contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59));

 // Return : 9/14/2010 3:59:00 PM
```

I have almost test my Time format with a Debug method, this return me the same format.

```
 // Return : 6/14/2010 3:55:00 AM
```

But My If statement return me always False.

Do someone have an idea of why the test :

```
if (Time == contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59))
```

is always False ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your own code using the **[free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** `The First Date is Time` it is hard to tell what that means, but there is no `Time`  type, and it is hard to tell how the format comes into play.

Comment: It's also an opportunity to learn how to format you code so it displays nicely on Stack Overflow.  Edit your question and try out the `{}` button. As it is, your code is borderline unreadable

Comment: And if you can't work out/don't have the {} button(eg mobile site), put (at least) 4 spaces at the start of every code line

Comment: Thanks for quiding me to use {} button, it's my first post on stack.

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format.  Formats are for parsing a string representation to a `DateTime` or for creating a string representation of the `DateTime`.  What you are comparing is whatever the value is of `Time` to the `Expiry` `DateTime` minus 56 hours and 1 minute.  Try putting both values into your debug statement and you'll see why they are not equal.

Comment: Yes this return me False, but i search a method to make it True.

Comment: Srry i misunderstood your answer Juharr, when you say "try putting both values into your debug statement" you mean Debug(" " + ....). I Use the quantconnect plateforme to code, there is not a built in debugger.

Comment: A `DateTime` represents a very precise instance in time (precise below the level of milliseconds, I believe). Unless you are controlling things exactly, equality comparisons between two DateTimes generally fail. Since you don't tell us what your `Time` represents or why you are adding/subtracting hours and minutes from your other DateTime (that we don't know anything about) we can't answer your question. Consider using the `Date` property of your DateTimes if you are trying to compare dates, or stripping off the milliseconds parts (using subtracting) before comparison

Comment: I mean add `Time` to the debug statement so you can see what it's value is compared to the other one.

Comment: By the way, by _"using the debugger"_, we mean putting a breakpoint in your code, and when it stops executing,  inspecting the values of your variables (the debugger uses the verb "watch" for this. Thanks, by the way for formatting your code

Comment: I have make a mistake in the title of the post, i dind't have to use the word DateTime but instead the word Date.

Comment: I edit the post i think it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example doesn't really make sense as it doesn't represent true C# code. My presumption is that you are trying to compare C# DateTime variable types and may be getting confused that when these DateTime variables are being converted to strings as in your outputs, they may "appear" to be the same, but when testing for equality you are getting a false result. This is because what is stored for a datetime (raw binary data) and what you see when you write it to the screen (effectively calling .ToString()) are two entirely different things.

DateTimes are effectively tracking time down to roughly the millisecond, even if it doesn't output that when you print it. Because of this, you can have two DateTime values that look the same, but reflect different values.

To see this try outputting the total Milliseconds or the Ticks values from each of your values:

```
Debug.Writeline(Time.Ticks);
Debug.Writeline(contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59).Ticks);
```

I suspect you will get two similar, but different numbers.

When comparing date-times for testing purposes, first pick a threshold where the times will be considered equivalent. If you only care about the time down to the minute, then we can use Minute as the threshold. From there we compare the times:

```
var comparisonTime = contractNSQ100.Expiry.AddHours(-57).AddMinutes(59);

bool areSame = Math.Abs((Time.Subtract(comparisonTime).TotalMinutes) < 1;
```

This will compare the two times and report back if they are the within 1 minute of each other. To determine whether they are within 1 second, change `TotalMinutes` to `TotalSeconds`. The `Math.Abs()` call affords the comparison to work whether the Time value is either slightly before or after the comparison time.

Comment: Hi Steve Py, thanks for your help. Unfortunatly i get the message "cannot convert from " bool" to "sbyte".

Comment: bool areSame = Math.Abs((Time.Subtract(comparisonTime).TotalMinutes) < 1)

Comment: There was a typo in my example: Corrected above, that last ")" should have been a semi-colon. ";".  If that is still resulting in an error, I'm not sure where a Signed Byte would be introduced. If you can update your question with the exact C# code your method is running that will help.